# Why are the blue dot and blue arrow unresponsive as Google Maps app?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using Google map for my Android app. Using myGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true), I do get the blue dot and occasionally the blue arrow upon moving the device. However, both of them seem very unresponsive and inaccurate compared to the Google Maps app itself.

What do I need to do to get my blue dot and blue arrow to work more smoothly?
[image]

Comment: Yes, I've found the location api not to be as accurate as that in Google Maps. Have you tried the new [FusedLocationProvider](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html) that Google announced this year at Google IO? It may be more accurate.

Comment: from what I can tell the new provider does exactly what you can do by specifying a `ACCURACY_HIGH` `Criteria` to your `LocationManager`. It's just that the new API makes it easier. So if you don't want to change your code a lot, that may be worth trying first. [Example here](https://github.com/atgheb/sun-status-app/blob/master/src/com/alimuzaffar/sunalarm/util/LocationUtils.java) on how to use Criteria.